# I18n using PHP gettext()

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, gettext

I am trying to translate my website using PHP gettext() for which I have implemented the following code:

```
if ( false === function_exists('gettext') ) {
    echo "You do not have the gettext library installed with PHP.";
    exit(1);
}
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
$localedir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/Locale';
echo $localedir . ': ';
bindtextdomain('messages', $localedir);

textdomain('messages');
echo gettext("Hello");
exit(0);
```

But it doesnot seem to work because it is echoing the same string what I pass in gettext().

I have created the *.po, *.mo files using poedit while following  https://blog.udemy.com/php-gettext/ tutorial.

The above code has been taken from https://github.com/nota-ja/php-gettext-example/blob/master/index.php

But while having such solutions I am unable to translate the given content. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: gettext should be function like this gettext(){}

Comment: and you dont have to check false function_exists will check if function exists or not

Comment: @Anil Shrestha gettext(){} is giving syntax error. Please elaborate what I should pass into gettext function. Moreover It seems to a path problem for translation files to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to equal to false with function_exists. function_exists will check if function exists or not

```
if (function_exists('gettext')) {
   // this function exists
}else{
     echo "You do not have the gettext library installed with PHP.";
    exit(1);
}
```